# How to use R to average multivariable replicates ( spectral NIR)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have NIR data from corn kernels that I want to average the replicates of, but cannot seem to figure out how to. My data:

```
> class(reps)
[1] "data.frame"
> glimpse(reps)
Rows: 681
Columns: 785
$ sample  <chr> "27R", "27R", "27R", "27R", "27R", "27R"~
$ kernel  <int> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5~
$ repeat. <int> 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2~
$ avg.PG  <dbl> 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15~
$ X904    <dbl> -0.08694145, -0.14850043, -0.17836093, -~
$ X905    <dbl> -0.08657089, -0.14849092, -0.17750645, -~
...
$ X1682   <dbl> -0.002266914, -0.003294964, -0.031371715~
$ X1683   <dbl> -0.003183641, -0.004761241, -0.031461630~
$ X1684   <dbl> -0.004193890, -0.006374959, -0.031560983~
```

My datasheet consists of a NIR spectral scan for five kernels from each parental line (sample), scanned in triplicate, as well as an average extraction value for each parental line. The NIR data is shown as reflectance value at 1nm wavelength intervals from 904-1684. I want to average the three repeats of each kernel into one, and reduce data set into something like this

```
Rows: 227
Columns: 784
$ sample  <chr> "27R", "27R", "27R", "27R", "27R", "28"~
$ kernel  <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,~
$ avg.PG  <dbl> 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 70.20 ~
$ X904    <dbl> -0.1379343, ..., ~
...
$ X1684   <dbl> -0.01404328, ..., ~
```

where the repeats are averaged at each wavelength, in order to create a more accurate reading. The problem is I have no idea how to do this across the entire spectral data. I have tried to group rows into the three repeats per kernel and average each reflectance per wavelenght with:

```
avgreps<- reps %>% group_by(sample, kernel, repeat.)%>%
  summarise(across(.cols = X904:X1684, mean))
```

the code produces a rearranged data set without the avg. PG, but not the spectral means, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I cannot use slice() on a set interval, as I have already cleaned the data by removing abnormal replicates, so not every kernel has all three, so I'm out of ideas, and I can't find any example code for averaging multivariate data like spectra data. I am  new to R and only familiar with the basics, so I'm lost on how to wrangle the code into working for me. Thank you for any help you can give
...
[quick example in excel of data and how I'm trying to average data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opNNv.png)

SOLVED

alright so I might be an idiot, but also I think I have figured part of the problem out. It looks like the issue was I had numbered the replicates as 1, 2, 3 , so when sorting R assumed each was unique sample, which is the opposite of what I was going for. I removed the repeat column from my code so :

```
avgreps<- reps %>% group_by(sample, kernel, )%>%
  summarise(across(.cols = X904:X1684, mean))
```

which gave me the 230 obs of 783 var that I was looking for! I need to stop it from removing my additional components but finally getting somewhere.

```
avgreps1<- reps %>% group_by(sample, avg.PG, kernel, )%>%
  summarise(across(.cols = X904:X1684, mean))
```

If anyone runs into same problem, here is the code that worked for me

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and your expected output based on the example

Comment: structure(list(sample = c("27R", "27R", "27R", "27R", "27R", 
"27R"), kernel = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), repeat. = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), avg.PG = c(51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 51.15, 
51.15), X904 = c(-0.086941447, -0.148500428, -0.178360935, -0.129331896, 
-0.12600098, -0.125370052), X1684 = c(-0.00419389, -0.006374959, 
-0.031560983, -0.016765456, -0.016227147, -0.034309674)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame") 
output :
structure(list(sample = c("27R", "27R", "27R",), kernel = c(1L, 2L, 3L, ),  avg.PG = c(51.15, 51.15, 51.15)  X904 = c(-0.138,), X1684 = c(-0.014,)

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is.  Your dput shows only a single observation per group (sample, kernel, repeat.)

Comment: yes, I removed most of the spectral data, as it gets very bulky, and just showed the reading for the 1st (904) and last (1684) wavelength. But each sample has a reading matching the specific wavelength for a total of 780 datapoints per scan

Comment: If you can update your post with a small example that shows the issue and the expected output for that example, it would be easier

Comment: Perhaps your `summarise` got masked with `plyr::summarise`, try changing the code to `dplyr::summarise(across(.cols = X904:X1684, mean))`